# Using plugin-transform-react-jsx in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to transform some jsx dynamically in CRA.
(Newbie in these things....)

Was able to add plugins to CRA following https://devinschulz.com/modify-create-react-apps-babel-configuration-without-ejecting/

**I am not able to "transform" JSX code.**

Specifically uncommenting the line bellow results in the following err:

**unknown: Unexpected token (1:0)> 1 |**

```
import React from 'react'
var core = require("@babel/core");
export default function App() {
  core.transform('2 + 2');
  // core.transform('<div></div>');
  const obj = {}
  const prop = obj.foo?.bar?.() ?? 'foo bar'
  return <div className="App">{prop}</div>
}
```

Note that the other plugin seems to work correctly, as well vanilla JS.

config-overrides.js is:

```
const { override, addBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugins(
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'
  )
)
```

**Any help would be highly highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing and calling `addBabelPlugins`, use `addExternalBabelPlugins`

Also if you are using the plural call, `Plugins` instead of `Plugin`, be sure to spread the call

So your `config-overrides.js` would contain:

```
const { override, addExternalBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
  ...addExternalBabelPlugins(
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'
  )
)
```